vue-html2pdf page break and background doesn't fill all height of page
PLEASE HELP!
I'm trying to generate a pdf using vue-html2pdf.
I have a component that generate the infos and send to my ExportToPdf.vue component:
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn @click="generate" color="primary" :outlined="outlined" :block="block" :large="largeButton">
      <v-icon v-text="buttonIcon" left />
      {{ buttonText }}
    </v-btn>

    <vue-html2pdf :show-layout="false" :float-layout="true" :enable-download="download" :preview-modal="previewModal"
      :paginate-elements-by-height="1122" :filename="fileName" :pdf-quality="quality" :manual-pagination="true"
      :pdf-format="format" :pdf-margin="margin" :pdf-orientation="orientation" :pdf-content-width="width"
      ref="html2Pdf">
      <section slot="pdf-content" class="pdf-content">
        <slot name="content" />
      </section>
    </vue-html2pdf>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueHtml2pdf from 'vue-html2pdf'

export default {
  name: 'ExportToPDF',
  components: { VueHtml2pdf },

  props: {
    fileName: { type: String, default: 'PDF_File' },
    quality: { type: [String, Number], default: 2 },
    margin: { type: [String, Number], default: 0 },
    format: { type: String, default: 'a4' },
    orientation: { type: String, default: 'portrait' },
    width: { type: String, default: '810px' },
    buttonIcon: { type: String, default: 'mdi-file-download' },
    buttonText: { type: String, default: 'Exportar para PDF' },
    largeButton: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    block: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    outlined: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    download: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    previewModal: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  },

  methods: {
    async generate() {
      await this.$refs.html2Pdf.generatePdf()
    },
  },
}
</script>

But the background from another component is not filling all the second page. And the margin is not woking, so it's breaking the text in the middle.
Print of issues
I'm trying to break page with margin and fill the page with my background.
Edit. Here's my component:
<template>
    <div>
        <ExportToPDF :button-text="buttonText" :button-icon="buttonIcon" :file-name="pdfName" large-button
            :outlined="outlined" :block="block" :download="false" :previewModal="true">
            <template v-slot:content>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- COLUNA AUXILIAR -->
                        <div class="col-4 black-text justify-content-center" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                            <div class="flex-content">
                                <a href="https://carreirarh.com/" target="_blank">
                                    <div class="carreira-logo" />
                                </a>
                                <div class="subtitle">
                                    APAIXONADA PELO POTENCIAL HUMANO
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="userAvatar">
                                <UserAvatar :url="avatarUrl" :size="100" :name="candidateName" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-between text-center">
                                <div class="flex-content contatos-container">
                                    <h3
                                        style="padding-top: 20px; color: #195190; text-align: center; margin-left: 13px;">
                                        CONTATOS</h3>
                                    <v-list-item v-if="value && value != 'null'" dense
                                        v-for="({ value, src }, i) in candidateInfo " :key="i">
                                        <v-list-item-icon style="margin-left: 10px; color: #195190;">
                                            <v-icon color="#195190" v-text="src" size="18" />
                                        </v-list-item-icon>
                                        <v-list-item-subtitle class="black-text break-word">
                                            {{ value }}
                                        </v-list-item-subtitle>
                                    </v-list-item>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- COLUNA PRINCIAL -->
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <div class="resume-header px-0" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: -10px; width: 500px;">
                                <h3 class="candidate-name px-0">
                                    {{ candidateName.toUpperCase() }}
                                </h3>
                                <v-card-text class="px-0" v-if="candidateAreas" style="margin: 0 20px 0 -10px;">
                                    {{ candidateAreas.toUpperCase() }}
                                </v-card-text>
                            </div>

                            <div class="d-flex flex-column overflow-x-hidden"
                                style="margin: -25px 0px 0px 10px; margin-left: 20px;">
                                <CandidateExperiences v-if="candidateId" :candidate-id="candidateId"
                                    :candidate-view="candidateView" large hide-icon show-description hide-empty-section
                                    show-header :showCompany="true" :customClass="'montserrat-font'"
                                    :styleTitle="{ 'font-weight': '600', color: 'gray' }" />

                                <CandidateAcademicFormation v-if="candidateId" :candidate-id="candidateId"
                                    :candidate-view="candidateView" large hide-icon show-degree hide-empty-section
                                    show-header :customClass="'montserrat-font'"
                                    :styleTitle="{ 'font-weight': '600', color: 'gray' }" />

                                <CandidateCourses v-if="candidateId" :candidate-id="candidateId"
                                    :candidate-view="candidateView" large hide-icon show-description hide-empty-section
                                    show-header :customClass="'montserrat-font'"
                                    :styleTitle="{ 'font-weight': '600', color: 'gray' }" />

                                <CandidateLanguages v-if="candidateId" :candidate-id="candidateId"
                                    :candidate-view="candidateView" large hide-icon show-description hide-empty-section
                                    show-header :customClass="'montserrat-font'"
                                    :styleTitle="{ 'font-weight': '600', color: 'gray' }" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </template>
        </ExportToPDF>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import CandidateAcademicFormation from '@/components/selective_process/CandidateAcademicFormation.vue'
import CandidateCourses from '@/components/selective_process/CandidateCourses.vue'
import CandidateExperiences from '@/components/selective_process/CandidateExperiences.vue'
import CandidateLanguages from '@/components/selective_process/CandidateLanguages.vue'
import UserAvatar from '@/components/user/UserAvatar';
import ExportToPDF from '@/components/general/ExportToPDF.vue'

export default {
    name: 'CandidatePersonalResume',

    props: {
        candidateName: { type: String, default: '' },
        candidateInfo: { type: [Array], default: () => [] },
        candidateDescription: { type: String, default: '' },
        candidateId: { type: [String, Number], default: 0 },
        candidateAreas: { type: [String, Array], default: '' },
        avatarUrl: { type: String, default: '' },
        block: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        outlined: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        candidateView: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        buttonBlock: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        buttonText: { type: String, default: 'Ver Currículo' },
        buttonIcon: { type: String, default: 'mdi-eye-outline' },
    },

    components: {
        CandidateAcademicFormation,
        CandidateExperiences,
        CandidateCourses,
        UserAvatar,
        ExportToPDF,
        CandidateLanguages,
    },

    data() {
        return {
            candidateHasAcademicFormation: false,
            candidateHasOtherCourses: false,
            candidateHasExperiences: false,
        }
    },

    computed: {
        logo() {
            return require('@/assets/logo.png')
        },

        pdfName() {
            const nameWithoutSpaces = this.candidateName.replace(' ', '_')
            return `Curriculo_${nameWithoutSpaces}`
        },
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.montserrat-font {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #fff 66.7%, #f4f4f5 66.7%) repeat-y;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-padding {
    padding: 0px 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-between {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-content {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.white-text {
    color: #fff;
}

.black-text {
    color: #00000099;
}

.resume-header {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0px 20px 25px 0;
    min-height: 180px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    justify-items: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: var(--v-secondary-lighten2);
    font-weight: 300;
}

.resume-header span {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.info-header {
    min-height: 180px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    justify-items: flex-start;
    align-items: flex-start;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.candidate-name {
    color: var(--v-primary-base);
    font-size: 38px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 0 20px 5px 0;
    font-weight: 800;
    bottom: 0;
    font-style: normal;
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.candidate-name span {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: var(--v-secondary-lighten2);
    font-weight: 300;
    font-style: italic;
}

.candidate-name span:before {
    content: '';
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 12px;
}

.carreira-logo {
    background-image: url('../../assets/logo.png');
    background-position-y: center;
    background-position-x: center;
    background-size: 200px auto;
    min-height: 110px;
}

.subtitle {
    margin-top: -20px;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: var(--v-secondary-lighten2);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.userAvatar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.v-list-item {
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.col-4 .black-text .justify-content-center {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.contatos-container {
    width: 225px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.break-word {
    font-size: 10px;
    white-space: normal;
    word-break: break-word;
}

.container {
    height: 100%;
}
</style>


Bit hard to help without knowing the content you're attempting to convert to PDF

When manual pagination is true you need to add a tag <div class="html2pdf__page-break"/> to manually break the page so that any content after this will be on the next page.
